# How to enforce c89-style variable declarations in VS2013

Tags: c

Does anybody know if there is some kind of pedantic flag in VS2013 to enforce c89 standard variable declarations. I know everyone will think me a nut but I liked it that way once I got used to it.

Comment: Do you mean to forbid mixing declarations and code? Also forbid declarations in `for` loops? Do you want to use other C99-features? (MSVC's support for them is partial anyway.)

Comment: The c89 standard required variable declarations to preceed the code. Interleaved declarations were not allowed. I wish to retain the old c89 standard in this regard if I can.

Comment: Don't know if this works in VS2013, but it does in older versions: Right click on your project, click `Properties`, expand `Configuration Properties`, expand `C/C++`, click `Advanced`, change `Compile As` to `Compile as C Code (/TC)`. I think this is as close as you can get to the C89 standard with Visual Studio.

Comment: You could install GCC and aim for no warnings with `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic`.

Comment: Well perhaps I should try using gcc. I have always wanted the time to try. But will the result run on windows7 and windows8 and all that rot, or am I expecting too much?

Comment: Using [clang-cl](http://llvm.org/builds/) and `-Xclang -std=gnu89 -Werror=declaration-after-statement` as additional command line options might be a preferable alternative to using GCC.

Comment: @cremno: The `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` option (with `-Werror`) is a more precise way of preserving the no declarations after statements semantic without throwing away other features that might be regarded as beneficial (such as `long long` -- though that might only be rejected with `-pedantic`).

Comment: Do you want a C89 compiler, or a C99 compiler which warns about declarations following a statement?

Comment: @mafso I want a c99 compiler that warns about declarations after a statement.

Comment: @Peter your question says "enforce" but your comment says "warning". If that is your preferred style why do you need either?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no such option in current incarnation of VS 2013 along with `cl` compiler. There is [`/Za`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) switch to disable language extensions, but C99 mixing declarations with code is [new feature in VS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx), that is defined by language itself.

See also [Disabling mixed declarations and C code in VS2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f1d4f803-2ae3-4a48-bdff-c3fafe58f11c/disabling-mixed-declarations-and-c-code-in-vs2013?forum=visualstudiogeneral).

Comment: I would agree that there is no compiler flag in VS2013 that will do what I want at present.

Comment: There is a workaround, but it is a bad way of going about things. In the project properties - Configuration Properties - General - Platform Toolset: Change to Visual Studio 2012 (v110). But remember after compiling that you probably want to change it back again to what it was.